# Visual Studio Code on Mac - C++ - Missing Documentation in Intellisense

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

VSCode on Mac won't show parameter information documentation through Intellisense for standard library includes.

[image: standard library includes]

It seems to work for my own defined functions though.

[image: local docs]

Is there an option that I'm missing to properly configure this?

Comment: Here in 2020 having the same problem. A answer would be very nice

Comment: Yes, couldn't also have it working, I'm on macOS also...